# How can I upgrade my Sql Server CE 3.5 sdf database to Sql Server CE 4.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I need to update my SqlCE3.5 database to 4.0.

I get the following error message when I'm trying to access my 3.5 sdf/database using the new CE4.0 connection provide :-

> System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeInvalidDatabaseFormatException: The database file has been created by an earlier version of SQL Server Compact. **Please upgrade using SqlCeEngine.Upgrade() method**.

Anyone know how I can do this? Obviously I need to do it programatcially but i'm not sure what I should do / what references I need to add, etc.

Cheers!

Comment: Is it not obvious? Call `SqlCeEngine.Upgrade()`! Or is there a problem? Also note incompatibilities between the different versions.

Comment: Hint: some code examples, please. When i tried some code, it couldn't compile.

Comment: See my blog post here for sample code: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-upgrade-version-3x-database-file.html

Comment: where do i find the SqlCE 4.0 dll i need to reference? (it's not listed in the .NET references). Can i NuGet it?

Comment: @leppie: i) Where? In what context? With what arguments? ii) SqlCeEngine doesn't contain a method named Upgrade(). The message is useless.

Comment: @ErikEJ your blog is awesome. Simple and yummy cake. Just eat it.

Comment: Will this work in upgrading from 2.0 to 4.0? I maintain a midievel app that uses version 2.0. I would like to at least be able to view the data in a utility so that I can easily see what's in those tables.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Call `System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeEngine.Upgrade`. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896160.aspx), which contains sample code.

Answer (score 10):

You needn't upgrade when you see this error:

> The database file has been created by an earlier version of SQL Server Compact. Please upgrade using SqlCeEngine.Upgrade() method.

Simply:

1. Right-click your Project in Solution Explorer
2. Choose properties, go to References tab
3. You'll see a reference called: `System. Data.SqlServerCe Type/net version/4.0` - delete this item (select item and then click remove in the bottom of this window).
4. Click on the "add..." button left of the "remove" button
5. In the .NET tab, find `System.Data.SqlServerCe 3.5` and add this.
6. Compile your project!

I think this will work.

Comment: Yes, no need to upgrade, unless you need to. If you don't find System.Data.SqlServerCe in .NET Tab, add the reference from C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Desktop

Comment: This advice is quite presumptuous: Many people starting with Visual Studio 2015 won't likely have the v3.5 version of SqlServerCe on their machine. If you're going to suggest adding a reference to v3.5, any ideas for people on how to obtain that version if they do not have it on their system?

Comment: @Jazimov you are right, but I answered this question 3 years ago before your comment and in 2013 it was quite normal approach.