# MSSQLCE version detection & upgrade

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

This is my "Upgrade if needed" code:

```
        try
        {
            cn.Open();
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeInvalidDatabaseFormatException ex) 
        {
            //Try to upgrade
            SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(strConnection); 
            engine.Upgrade(strConnection);
            cn.Open();

        }
```

It upgrades v3.5 db to v4.0 in practice. Is there any better solution? It would be nice if I detect installed engine & DB version in use.

Comment: Duplicate post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744527/how-can-i-upgrade-my-sql-server-ce-3-5-sdf-database-to-sql-server-ce-4-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this for file version detection: [How can I upgrade my Sql Server CE 3.5 sdf database to Sql Server CE 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744527/how-can-i-upgrade-my-sql-server-ce-3-5-sdf-database-to-sql-server-ce-4-0)

And this code can detect the Engine versions installed:

```
    internal static bool IsV40Installed()
    {
        try
        {
            System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91");
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        try
        {
            var factory = System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
        }
        catch (System.ArgumentException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    internal static bool IsV35Installed()
    {
        try
        {
            System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91");
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        try
        {
            var factory = System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5");
        }
        catch (System.ArgumentException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't the question ask how to detect the version of the database file?  That's what I'd like to know how to do anyway.

Comment: See the first link in the reply

Comment: This is what I need: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-upgrade-version-3x-database-file.html