# Does Windows 8 Desktop Applications (Not Metro or Store apps) support SQL Server CE 3.5?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-8, sql-server-ce-3.5

Does Windows 8 Desktop Applications (Not Metro or Store apps) support SQL CE 3.5?

When I tried to work with SQL Server CE, I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeInvalidDatabaseFormatException
>   (0x80004005): The database file has been created by an earlier version
>   of SQL Server Compact. Please upgrade using SqlCeEngine.Upgrade()
>   method.

Thanks in advance,
Carlos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8 supports SQL Server CE. You have a different problem. You are trying to use older version of database file while you have a newer version of SQL Server CE

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744527/how-can-i-upgrade-my-sql-server-ce-3-5-sdf-database-to-sql-server-ce-4-0) question

Comment: Thank you! I change the reference to the SQLServerCE.dll 4.0 to the dll of the 3.5 version and its works! Thanks so much! :D